# HTML form with Javascript validation and PHP script which sends form details to webmaster by e-mail

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer

Complete newbie looking for some guidance. Will be very grateful if someone could help me out! Just want to confirm that the below is possible or if there is a better alternative, or I'm blatantly missing something!?

So, I'm developing a site with a simple form - it will take the user's name, email address, contact number and a message.

So as far as I understand I can do the following:

1.Write the form in HTML and style with CSS.
2.Validate the form client side with Javascript
3.Use PHP to validate server side incase user has Javascript disabled.
4.Use PHP mailer to send the details to an email address where the site will be hosted. 
5.On page error or success message for the user to see.

Would really appreciate it if you could recommend resources which will guide me through the process.

Thanks a million!

Comment: You understand correctly. You can also use Google to find tutorials on creating simple web forms with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the PHP side of things, and use this pre-made secure script [NMS Formmail](http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/scripts.shtml).

There's no validation on that side, but I don't think you'll have to worry about it much. Worst case you'll get an incomplete email that you just have to toss.

JavaScript validation: http://webcheatsheet.com/javascript/form_validation.php
If those functions don't work, just look around, there are plenty of other examples.

Now all you have left is the HTML and CSS.